# What are the best practices for hosting Tezos nodes with exposed RPCs?

Tags: rpc, node, conseil

If i host my own node, e.g. like `TezBox` does, what's the best practice regarding accessibility of certain RPC endpoints?

TzScan already restricts certain calls, as [described here](http://mainnet-node.tzscan.io/).

Tezos [docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/howtouse.html#rpc-interface) advise as following:

> The RPC interface must be enabled in order for the clients to
>   communicate with the node, but is should not be publicly accessible on
>   the internet.

With the new [memory management update](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2019/01/30/improving-tezos-storage-update-and-beta-testing/), additional RPC endpoints will be available, and they might posses a danger if exposed publicly without knowing.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either:

- don't expose the RPC at all (!), or
- put a proxy in front with a maximally restrictive *whitelist*.

Of course, for a whitelist to help, you must not include potentially harmful endpoints in your whitelist... Even seemingly harmless endpoints might be used for denial of service, and some endpoints are surprisingly harmful.

Answer (score 10):

What we do for TezRPC (which powers TezBox) is run a proxy on each server. Within this proxy, you can then block, restrict and customize public facing endpoints.

We currently use a light proxy built with NodeJS, but will switch over to a nginx style proxy (better performance).

Here is an example of a node.js proxy that blocks almost all endpoints (listening to the local RPC API on port 8732):

```
var express = require('express');  
var request = require('request');
var app = express();  
var cors = require('cors')
var apiServerHost = "http://localhost:8732";
app.use(cors())
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    // Whitelist. Be afraid.
    if (req.url === '/chains/main/blocks/head'
          || req.url === '/chains/main/blocks/head/hash') {
        var url = apiServerHost + req.url;
        req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not available');
    }
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('TZProxy running')
})
```

Comment: So your blacklist here will allow the new endpoints in the question, for example. :(

Comment: I was simply posting an example of how to deploy a custom proxy, which is what the user is asking for. As mentioned, it blocks "some endpoints".

Comment: I was actually playing around with your nodes earlier today, noticed pretty long response times ~700ms (from Europe).

Comment: Yep hoping the nginx switch will speed it up

Comment: Proposing a blacklist approach is certainly less secure than using a restrictive whitelist. Since the question is related  to best practice, the answer could be improved by changing the example to a whitelist, the blacklist approach has many security shortcomings.  Owasp have a good resource on this topic https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Stephen - it could be related to geolocation as well, but that's not the main topic here.

Comment: I updated the example to use a whitelist. This will exclude old and new bad endpoints. For example, there was some idea to add [snapshot-related RPCs](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos/commit/3345423ebaa9b5ebd3f075124eaa7f0b47acaed3). I hope the two endpoints I allowed are reasonably safe...

Answer (score 6):

One of the alternatives i could think of, is using `Conseil`:
https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil

In my humble understanding what Conseil does, is provide an extended API on top of a tezos-node/rpc. And perhaps (?) some extra features which could allow enabling/disabling endpoints or other security measures.

[Here's a few examples](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil/blob/master/doc/Query.md)

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer ? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the comment with examples and explanation.

Answer (score 6):

When you only need the RPC for yourself you could also use ssh local port forwarding to forward the RPC from the localhost of your remote machine to the localhost of your local machine.

For instance, as a background process:

```
ssh -fNT -L 8732:localhost:8732 user@hostname
```

I don't know how safe this is though.

Answer (score 0):

This medium post: [Deploy Scalable Tezos Nodes in the Cloud](https://medium.com/the-aleph/deploy-scalable-tezos-nodes-in-the-cloud-bbe4f4f4ddcc) presents a method to deploy a RPC service on AWS using [Pulumi](https://pulumi.com) and [tezos-k8s](https://tezos-k8s.xyz).